# anything / everything but

Tags: grammaticality

With reference to a commonly bad behaviour (e.g. corruption), may I write/say:
"it seems to be everything but an Italian bad habit only!"?

Comment: No, you can’t say that. In fact, that sentence makes so little sense that I can’t figure out exactly what you _want_ it to say. Please clarify.

Comment: No, you may not. Not with that phrasing. This sentence is seriously overnegated and nobody will understand what you're claiming, nor whether it's true of Italians only, or whether you're absolving Italians.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your comment, I believe your point is that corruption is a bad habit that applies to many countries or societies.  Although stereotypes may associate it with Italians, it is definitely not *only* Italian.

I think for "everything but" you likely meant "anything but".

> Corruption is a wide-spread bad habit; it is anything but exclusively Italian.

Answer (score 0):

Your phrase seems a little odd but I think what you are trying to say is : "It seems to be a disrespectful Italian habit" maybe?

That should fix it

Comment: I'm sorry. I will try to better explain what I mean : reading an article about the corruption trend within the western countries, I noted that this kind of act up seems to be a really sensitive trouble regarding most democracies, even if in the past many media used to stereotype this as a sort of Italian habit.

Comment: Oh right, I must've passed the word corruption..